# Lowest Common Ancestor of multiple nodes in a n-ary tree

Tags: java, tree, nlp, text-processing, graph-algorithm

I am trying to implement LCA of multiple nodes in an n-ary tree in java. I am working with parse trees of sentences, So its reasonable to assume that number of children of a node <= 6. Multiple nodes here are two phrases(continuous word sequence) in a sentence. Let k be the number of nodes involved.

One way is to find the LCA of two nodes for k/2 pairs and we will get k/2 nodes. Now recurse on these k/2 nodes. The order will be O(nlog k), where O(n) is the complexity of linear LCA finding algorithms. Can I do it more efficiently ?

Comment: I think the complexity is O(n. k) not O(n. log(k)). You will have log(k) steps of k/2, k/4.. which is O(k).

Comment: @VSOverFlow I'll have log(k) steps and each step takes O(n), therefore, overall its O(nlog k). What is O(k) in your calculations?

Comment: I am assuming that LCA(2,n) is O(n). When you build the binary tree the total number of LCA calls is O(k) (k/2+k/4+....). So total runtime complexity is O(n * k) (i.e. k calls of O(n)). Each of log(k) steps has many O(n) steps (k/2, k/4, k/8,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the fact that the nodes of the phrases are continuous i.e. have continuous indices in the list of leaf nodes of a parse tree.

Let `segment1` have indices from `start1` to `end1`. Same be the case for `segment2 = (start2,end2)`.

The Required Common Ancestor of `(start1, end1)` and `(start2, end2)` is the common ancestor of nodes with indices `min(start1,start2)` and `max(end1,end2)`.

Comment: can you please give full method? I am not able to convert your algorithm into actual code.

Comment: The idea is that if all nodes are consecutive leaf nodes, the LCA of all these nodes will be the LCA of first and last node.